# If aircraft specific energy is a combination of kinetic and potential energy, why is altitude not a variable in the energy-maneuverability theory?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-physics, theory

The Energy-Manueverability formula is

$$ P_S = V \left( \frac{T - D}{W} \right) $$

with velocity $V$, thrust $T$, drag $D$ and weight $W$.

$P_s$ represents specific energy, which is a combination of potential and kinetic energy. What I want to know is this: if specific energy is a combination of kinetic and potential energy, why is altitude not a part of the formula?

Comment: It is. Potential energy is MgH, and the H is altitude (Height). Although *Specific* Energy is actually *specific* kinetic energy plus *specific* potential energy, which is actually energy per unit of mass. That's so we can compare specific energy of aircraft with widely differing masses with one another. The formula in your link is *NOT* specific Energy, it is Ps, or specific *Power*, which is different.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a fundamental misunderstanding: asking why the equation for specific power doesn't include a term expected to be found in the equation for specific energy.

Answer (score 3):

It is. Potential energy is MgH, and the H is altitude (Height). Although Specific Energy is actually specific kinetic energy plus specific potential energy, which is actually energy per unit of mass. That's so we can compare specific energy of aircraft with widely differing masses with one another. The formula in your link is NOT specific Energy, it is Ps, or specific Power, which is different.